# maven eclipse:eclipse order of source folders get lost

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Iin Eclipse it's possible to change the order via project settings (`Context menu` -> `Project settings`). Tab `Build Path`, there you can move folders up/down. Following this steps changes the order of source folders.

But after a `mvn eclipse:clean` -> `mvn eclipse:eclipse`, the changes get lost. Is there a solution to do that permanently?

I have also done my changes in my POM without success:

```
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
  </resource>

  <resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
<testSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you care about the order of source folders? It shouldn't matter.

Comment: Why do you use eclipse:eclipse and don't use m2e integration ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [M2Eclipse - Eclipse Maven Integration](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Use it to utilize powers of both Maven and Eclipse.

Maven can automatically manage your [projects dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html). For example [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library can be added to your project by inserting this to `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.1</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

if you have M2Eclipse in installed in your eclipse. New item *Maven Dependencies* will appear in Package Explorer under your project. And *Gson* library will be added to your classpaths.

You do not need to change dependencies order. They will be resolved by maven automatically.

Dependency management is one of [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html)'s main features. Use it.